# Android - Javascript Interface with pointer to WebView - how to achive it without memleak

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, garbage-collection

This is how I add JSInterface to Webview in Android app (we are inside of extended WebView Class):

```
addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "appBridge"); // 'this' is MyWebView that we are inside
```

Then constructor JSInterface stores 'this' to his protected variable, because JSInterface methods need access to WebView class.

But this way seems to lead to memory leaks. The MyWebView (created programatically) has pointer to JSInterface (addJavascriptInterface) and JSInterface has pointer to WebView. So they can't be removed from memory by Garbage Collector. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView will hold your object (the instance of JSInterface) until you call `removeJavascriptInterface("appBridge")` and reload your page.

But this kind of a circular reference isn't actually a problem for a mark-compact collector (used in languages with built-in garbage collection, like Java or JavaScript), because once such looped construction doesn't have any references from the outside (that is, you have eliminated your last reference to the WebView instance), it will be collected as unreachable:

```
app ---> WebView --> JSInterface  | both WebView and JSInterface are reachable
           ^            |
           --------------

      /
app -/-> WebView --> JSInterface  | now this looped construction
    /      ^            |         | is unreachable and will be collected
           --------------
```

You are probably confusing this with reference counting (which is often used in languages like C++), where indeed mutual hard references from one object to another will cause them to remain forever.

And a side note -- if you care about your memory usage, don't forget to call `WebView.destroy()` once you don't need it and have removed it from the views hierarchy to free up resources used by native code.

Answer (score 0):

add something like

```
jsInterface.setWebview(null);
```

inside of your activity onDestroy() or pass your webview in method parameters instead of using a class field.

Comment: But there isn't any guarantee that onDestroy will be called.

Comment: otherwise, pass your webview in method parameter instead of using a class field.

Comment: And in my program the WebView variable can exists without Activity in foreground Service. (Activity and Service are in same thread) so If Activity will be onDestroy'ed WebView(and JS in it) still works

Comment: You also have an onDestroy method in a service. The thing is "tell to jsInterface when it can be released" ;)

Comment: so I shouldn't care that onDestroy may not be called (while it should, this can happen)?

Comment: imho you should do your release stuffs when the Activity or Service must be destroyed. If the onDestroy is not called, it's because of another problem. Then it is necessary to investigate this other issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78924/discussion-between-elsajko-and-mederic).